# Label aligment in Google ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, keen-io

I'm having trouble trying to changing the position of the labels in this Google ColumnChart. The chart is rendered via the Keen.io JS SDK. I've got a very tight space to work in and I'm trying to position the labels underneath the chart instead of on the right hand side (where the label text is truncated). Here is a screenshot -

[image: graph]

I've included my config object below. Is there an option I'm missing - nothing to seems to shift the labels from the right hand side. Thanks.

```
{
            chartType: 'columnchart',
            chartOptions: {
                isStacked: true
            },
            fontName : 'Helvetica',
            fontSize : '11px',
            width : 270,
            height : 220,
            chartArea : {
                left : 0,
                top : 0,
                width : '100%',
                height : '100%'
            },
            colors : ['#abdd99', '#8dc7d9', '#eeeeee'],
            colorMapping : {
                'pro' : '#abdd99',
                'basic' : '#8dc7d9'
            },
            labelMapping: {
                "basic": "BASIC",
                "pro": "PRO"
            },
            title : 'PROFILE VIEWS',
            vAxis : {
                viewWindowMode : 'maximized',
                gridlines : { color : '#eeeeee' },
                baselineColor : '#eeeeee',
                textPosition : 'none'
            },
            hAxis : {
                viewWindowMode : 'maximized',
                gridlines : {
                    color : '#eeeeee'
                },
                baselineColor : '#eeeeee',
                textPosition : 'none'
            },
            legend : {
                position : 'bottom',
                textStyle : {
                    color : '#cccccc',
                    fontName : 'Helvetica',
                    fontSize : '11px'
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those Google-specific configurations should go inside of `chartOptions` object. Give this a try and let me know how it goes:

```
{
  chartType: 'columnchart',
  chartOptions: {
    fontName : 'Helvetica',
    fontSize : '11px',
    isStacked: true,
    chartArea : {
      left : 0,
      top : 0,
      width : '100%',
      height : '100%'
    },
    vAxis : {
      viewWindowMode : 'maximized',
      gridlines : { color : '#eeeeee' },
      baselineColor : '#eeeeee',
      textPosition : 'none'
    },
    hAxis : {
      viewWindowMode : 'maximized',
      gridlines : {
        color : '#eeeeee'
      },
      baselineColor : '#eeeeee',
      textPosition : 'none'
    },
    legend : {
      position : 'bottom',
      textStyle : {
        color : '#cccccc',
        fontName : 'Helvetica',
        fontSize : '11px'
      }
    }
  },
  width : 270,
  height : 220,
  colors : ['#abdd99', '#8dc7d9', '#eeeeee'],
  colorMapping : {
    'pro' : '#abdd99',
    'basic' : '#8dc7d9'
  },
  labelMapping: {
    "basic": "BASIC",
    "pro": "PRO"
  },
  title : 'PROFILE VIEWS'
}
```

Update: You might also enjoy working with [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) more.. we added a C3 adapter in v3.1. Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating how to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/keen/0mL925vr/

Comment: Great, that's done the trick - thanks! I'll check out C3 too :)

Comment: Great, happy to hear that @Phil!